# How to convert datatype - child object level in mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongo-shell

I have following documents,

like,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a5446dddadff101aea67c6"),
    "SubMenu" : [
        {
            "subMenuIconPath" : "images/hr/emp.png",
            "screenID" : "Service Maintenance",
            "subMenuName" : "Service Maintenance",
            "orderBy" : 1.0,
            "menuID" : "300"
        },
        {
            "subMenuIconPath" : "images/hr/emp.png",
            "screenID" : "Process Template Maintenance",
            "subMenuName" : "Process Template Maintenance",
            "orderBy" : 2.0,
            "menuID" : "300"
        }
    ],
    "level" : "PARENT",
    "orderBy" : 3,
    "menuType" : "List",
    "appID" : "dais-admin",
    "menuName" : "Process and Service",
    "menuID" : "300",
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a5446dddadff101aea67c7"),
    "SubMenu" : [
        {
            "subMenuIconPath" : "images/hr/emp.png",
            "screenID" : "User Maintenance",
            "subMenuName" : "User Maintenance",
            "orderBy" : 1.0,
            "menuID" : "100"
        },
        {
            "subMenuIconPath" : "images/hr/emp.png",
            "screenID" : "Role/ACL Maintenance",
            "subMenuName" : "Role/ACL Maintenance",
            "menuID" : "100"
        }],
    "level" : "PARENT",
    "orderBy" : 1,
    "menuType" : "List",
    "appID" : "dais-admin",
    "menuName" : "Security Settings",
    "menuID" : "100",
}
```

Execute mongo command, change converted DOUBLE value to INTEGER for within array element of SubMenu.orderBy.

Note : SubMenu have Multiple Documents. And sometime SubMenu.orderBy Value is null also.

Can someone help me on this.

Comment: are you  looking for mongo shell command to convert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert dataType you can execute command in Mongo-shell,

By using update statment in forEach we can alter every single document.

```
    db.collection.find({
        SubMenu: {
            $exists: true
        }
    }).forEach(function(myDoc) {
        var child = myDoc.SubMenu;
        for (var i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
            var ob = child[i];
            if ('orderBy' in ob) {
                ob.orderBy = NumberInt(ob.orderBy);
                child[i] = ob;
            }

        }
        db.collection.update({
            _id: myDoc._id
        }, {
            $set: {
                subMenu: child
            }
        });
        printjson(myDoc);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this command

```
db.menu.find({
    SubMenu: {
        $exists: true
    }
}).forEach(function(obj) {
    obj.SubMenu.forEach(function(childobject) {
        if (childobject.orderBy != null) {
            childobject.orderBy = NumberInt(childobject.orderBy);
        }
    });
    db.menu.save(obj);
    printjson(obj);
});
```